# How do I end a client server transmission after it hits a limit of 10

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm new to networking and need some help with completing the transmission after it transmits ten strings.

Here's the my server side

```
import socket           
import time 
from string import capitalize
from test.test_urllib2net import CloseSocketTest
from findertools import shutdown

host = "localhost" 
port = 3030
data = "just some text"
data = data.encode('utf-8')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)        

while 1:
  s.sendto(data,(host,port))
  print (capitalize("sent " + data.decode('utf-8')))
  time.sleep(1)
```

client

```
import socket
from server import host
from string import capitalize

HOST = "localhost"
PORT = 3030

t = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

t.bind((HOST,PORT))

while 1:
   print (t.recv(50))
```

Comment: how about replacing `while 1:` with `for i in range(10):`?

Comment: YES! Thank you! Last question after the transmission how do  make it print "transmission complete"